# Recursive TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to do a recursive TreeView with IsVirtualizing turned on of the Model below:

```
    public class DataContainer
    {
        public List<DataEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataEntity
    {
        public uint m_dwID { get; set; }

        public int m_nMargineH { get; set; }
        public int m_nMargineV { get; set; }
        public int m_nPosX { get; set; }
        public int m_nPosY { get; set; }

        public List<DataEntity> m_pNEXT { get; set; }
    }
```

I have already tried tooling with microsoft's examples, but i can't make it working (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-a-treeview#code) 
Either it's showing the correct first level item name without an expanding button (to show its child items) or it shows something like '(collection)'

I'm not an expert in WPF so please bear with me :)

Comment: TreeView? where is TreeView? I don't it anythere in the code

Comment: @ASh Problem is that i don't have any idea how to do such a TreeView properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set the HierarchicalDataTemplate in a way that will recursively set the `m_pNEXT` children, here's an example:

**WPF:**

```
<TreeView Name="MyTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="177" Margin="126,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="247">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataEntity}" ItemsSource="{Binding m_pNEXT}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding m_dwID}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

**DataContainer example:**

```
MyTreeView.ItemsSource = new DataContainer
{
    Entities = new List<DataEntity>
    {
        new DataEntity
        {
            m_dwID = 1,
            m_pNEXT = new List<DataEntity>
            {
                new DataEntity
                {
                    m_dwID = 11
                },
                new DataEntity
                {
                    m_dwID = 12
                }
            }
        },

        new DataEntity
        {
            m_dwID = 2,
            m_pNEXT = new List<DataEntity>
            {
                new DataEntity
                {
                    m_dwID = 21,
                    m_pNEXT = new List<DataEntity>
                    {
                        new DataEntity
                        {
                            m_dwID = 211
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}.Entities;
```

**Results:**

[image: Result]

All you have to do now is play with the HierarchicalDataTemplate and show each item as you want, hope this helps you!

Comment: Oh my god thank you! I did not expect it to be THAT easy :O